# Log files is busy by another process with open

Tags: django, python-logging

I have script which get information from log file and create model with log info from that file when user log in or log out on our site

But when I'm restarting the PC, I got an error that my log file is busy by another process.

How can i fix that?

script.py

```
def writing_logs(request, action):
    logger.info('{} {} {} {}'.format(
        request.user.email,
        get_client_ip(request),
        get_client_type_device(request),
        action))

    with open('loggers/log_user_activity/user_activity.log', 'r', encoding='utf8') as filelog:
        for i_line in filelog.readlines():
            if i_line.startswith('INFO') and len(i_line.split()) == 9:
                line_list = i_line.split()
                if line_list[3] != 'Watching':
                    if not Log.objects.filter(log_date=line_list[1]):
                        Log.objects.create(log_category=line_list[0],
                                           log_date=line_list[1])
```